# vertical and horizontal centering doesn't work as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) framework in which I have this markup:

```
<header id="home" data-scroll-index="0">
 <div class="Center-Container is-Table">
      <div class="Table-Cell">
        <div class="Center-Block">
            <h1>DUMMY TEXT</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

and this css styles:

```
#home { 
background:url(../img/bg.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
color: white;
height: 800px;
margin: 0;
}

 .Center-Container.is-Table { display: table; }
 .is-Table .Table-Cell {
  display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
   }
 .is-Table .Center-Block {
 width: 50%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 z-index:999999;
  }
```

But it doesn't center vertically and horizontally and I don't understand why. Can someone explain me what am I doing wrong? 
Here is a fidlle: http://jsfiddle.net/WY37a/

Comment: i think you have a typo `.Center-Container.is-Table` should be  `.Center-Container .is-Table`

Comment: The problem in your case is that the is-Table has the same height and width as Table-cell where as it should be equivalent to header's height and width. Check my answer for a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your case is that the `is-Table` has the same height and width as `Table-cell` where as it should be equivalent to header's height and width.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WY37a/2/)**

You can remove the is-Table div

```
#home {
    background:url(http://catexcomp.ro/nevermore/img/bg.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    color: white;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.Table-Cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.Center-Block {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index:999999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#home { 
    background:url(http://catexcomp.ro/nevermore/img/bg.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    color: white;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0;
   }

.Center-Container.is-Table { 
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.is-Table .Table-Cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.is-Table .Center-Block {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index:999999;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WY37a/3/)

Comment: i think you have a typo `.Center-Container.is-Table`

Comment: Nope. Look at the OP's HTML.. it's not the best way to target CSS selectors, but this is a whole different topic.